# What does TERM=dumb in eshell mean?

Tags: eshell

In `eshell`, if I `echo $TERM`, the result is `dumb`. What does this mean? Is this an emacs specific thing, or a tty thing?

Answer (score 4):

First, it's an Emacs thing. It tells the used shell, that the buffer for input/output has only limited capabilities. See the following comment and code in `lisp/startup.el`:

> ```
> ;; Subprocesses of Emacs do not have direct access to the terminal, so
> ;; unless told otherwise they should only assume a dumb terminal.
> ;; We are careful to do it late (after term-setup-hook), although the
> ;; new multi-tty code does not use $TERM any more there anyway.
> (setenv "TERM" "dumb")
> ```

It is also an OS specific setting, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminals

Comment: That comment suggests to me that it's a convention outside of just emacs.